# Border Width Issue with Corner Radius in UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm encountering an issue when attempting to set a border width for a UIView with a corner radius in Swift. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var borderView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Setting corner radius causes border width issue
        borderView.layer.cornerCurve = .continuous
        borderView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        borderView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        borderView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    }
}
```

In this code, I'm setting a corner radius on borderView along with a border color and width. However, the border width appears incorrect when the corner radius is applied. Interestingly, when no corner radius is set, the border width displays correctly.

I've tried using borderView.layer.borderColor and borderView.layer.borderWidth directly. Unfortunately, my approach do not resolved the issue.

I've attached an image below to illustrate the problem:
[Illustration of Border Width Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0Tlu.png)

Can anyone provide insights or suggest an alternative approach to achieve a consistent border width around a UIView with a corner radius? It's worth noting that the border width displays correctly when no corner radius is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are trying to draw a line that is not a whole number of pixels wide. This will look different depending on whether the line is pixel-aligned.

On scale=3 screens (presumably what you are using), one pixel is 1/3 points, but you are trying to draw a line 1/2 points wide. This is just a little bit bigger than one pixel. At some points of the drawing, the alignment looks like this:

[image]

The thin blue squares represent the pixels, and the thick line represents the border of the line that you are trying to draw. As you can see, the line's width completely covers one pixel, plus a little bit of the pixels besides it. The end result is that the line of pixels that got covered is drawn.

[image]

At another point, the line is aligned differently for some reason (perhaps some implementation detail of the rounded rect-drawing code). The alignment becomes something like this:

[image]

It doesn't entirely cover any one line of pixels. It does cover "most" of two lines of pixels though, so those two lines gets drawn, perhaps with one of them filled with a slightly lighter color, depending on the actual proportion of the pixel being covered.

[image]

See also these related questions:

- [Why do lines smaller than 1.0pts not render correctly on non-retina screens?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17075289/5133585)
- [Core Graphics is not drawing a line at the correct width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10008286/5133585)

If you just want to draw a 1-pixel wide line, set the width to `1 / UIScreen.main.scale` like the first post above suggested. Multiples of `1 / UIScreen.main.scale` doesn't seem to be affected by the changes in alignment caused by drawing a rounded rect.

Also note that if you hand-write the drawing code yourself, by writing out all the coordinates, then all the straight lines will be aligned the same way.

```
class SomeView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: .init(x: rect.minX + 20, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.maxX - 20, y: rect.minY))
        path.addArc(withCenter: .init(x: rect.maxX - 20, y: rect.minY + 20), radius: 20, startAngle: 3 * .pi / 2, endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
        path.move(to: .init(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY + 20))
        path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY - 20))
        path.addArc(withCenter: .init(x: rect.maxX - 20, y: rect.maxY - 20), radius: 20, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi / 2, clockwise: true)
        path.move(to: .init(x: rect.maxX - 20, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.minX + 20, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addArc(withCenter: .init(x: rect.minX + 20, y: rect.maxY - 20), radius: 20, startAngle: .pi / 2, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: true)
        path.move(to: .init(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY - 20))
        path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY + 20))
        path.addArc(withCenter: .init(x: rect.minX + 20, y: rect.minY + 20), radius: 20, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: 3 * .pi / 2, clockwise: true)
        path.lineWidth = 1 / 2
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

Note that this is an open path, which is different from the closed path that `CALayer` draws for its border. Also, the rounded corners drawn for the layer's border is a little different from the arc added by `addArc`. Perhaps that is why the pixels get aligned differently after drawing the arcs.